# Simple Custom Grid Control

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls

I'm designing a [Point and Figure Charting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_and_figure_chart) program, and my first version used the DataGridView control, which I found to be too big and bloated for my needs. All I need is a simple control that displays a square grid which will be filled with X's and O's.

The data is parsed from yahoo finance as Open, High, Low, Close data, sorted by a set of rules and converted to an Int Array, which will correspond with the index of the rows, so the simpler the control is, and the less bloat is has the more efficient it will be when chewing through large amounts of data.

I also need to be able to easily adjust the size of the squares in the grid, to zoom in and out of the data.

I am unfamiliar with creating custom controls (But willing to learn), and I'm not having a lot of luck with the search terms I'm using, so any help pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a couple of custom controls like this before usually colour/graphics related stuff and they usually end up being more work than you imagine.

In the last project where I needed to do custom display stuff (a massive matrix of TCPConnection status between many different machines) I just used Xceed's gridControl and dynamically added the columns to the control. I kept an internal dictionary of the index of the column I added so that subsequent rows could benefit from direct reference to the column.

There are many different grid controls that you could probably utilise. Or if you want to get down and dirty with a Custom Control using the **Pain**t stuff you can do that too.

property for Columns, Rows .. Calculate the Space available then draw your Horiz/Verticals then draw you other values in the correct spaces, but eek prepare to invest quite a bit of time getting it "just right"